# Why checkbox checked property doesn't change after detectChanges()

Tags: angular, jasmine, angular-test

I try to change checkbox checked property by changing model but it doesn't work. I cannot understand this behavior.

**Template**:

`<input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="model"/>`

**Testing Code**:

```
    it('should be checked after click on unchecked checkbox', () => {
        const checkbox: HTMLInputElement = fixture.nativeElement.querySelector('input');

        component.model = true;
        fixture.detectChanges();
        expect(checkbox.checked).toBeTruthy();
    });
```

Full code: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-testing-checkbox?file=app/app.component.spec.ts

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because angular change detection is asynchronous. Your `expect()` statement is executed before `detectChanges()`. Use angular testing `async()` function for this case:

```
   it('should be checked after click on unchecked checkbox', async( () => {
        const checkbox: HTMLInputElement = fixture.nativeElement.querySelector('input');    
        component.model = true;
        fixture.detectChanges();    
        fixture.whenStable().then(()=> {
          expect(checkbox.checked).toBeTruthy();
        })   
    }));
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `fixture.whenStable` together with the `done` function to synchronize the asynchronous change detection cycle with the `expect`.

```
it('should be checked after click on unchecked checkbox', (done) => {
    const checkbox: HTMLInputElement = fixture.nativeElement.querySelector('input');

    component.model = true;
    fixture.detectChanges();
    fixture.whenStable().then(() => {
      expect(checkbox.checked).toBe(true);
      done();
    });
});
```