# Angular 9 testing with Jest - why does this mat-checkbox test fail?

Tags: angular, testing, jestjs

I have a reset function in my component that resets all child checkboxes:

```
  @ViewChildren('checkBoxes') checkBoxes: QueryList<MatCheckbox>;

  /**
   * Mark all checkboxes as unchecked
   */
  reset() {
    this.checkBoxes.forEach((checkbox: MatCheckbox) => {
      console.log('i am being called' + checkbox.checked);
      checkbox.checked = false;
    });
  }
```

This is the test:

```
  it('should uncheck all checkboxes when reset is called', fakeAsync(() => {
    const checkboxInput = fixture.debugElement.query(
      By.css('.mat-checkbox-input')
    );
    const el = checkboxInput.nativeElement;
    el.click();
    component.reset();
    fixture.detectChanges();
    expect(el.checked).toBe(false);
  }));
```

I can see from the `console.log` that the reset function is called and the checkbox is true. But at the point the expect runs, it is still true when it should be false.

I tried adding a `tick()` after the `reset()` call, but it made no difference.

**UPDATE**

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58818537/why-checkbox-checked-property-doesnt-change-after-detectchanges) question, which is almost identical except they are changing the checkbox binding property on the component inside the test directly.  But anyway I tried this:

```
  it('should uncheck all checkboxes when reset is called', async(() => {
    const checkboxInput = fixture.debugElement.query(
      By.css('.mat-checkbox-input')
    );
    const el = checkboxInput.nativeElement;
    el.click();
    component.reset();
    fixture.detectChanges();
    fixture.whenStable().then(() => {
      expect(el.checked).toBe(false);
    });
  }));
```

but that also fails.

Comment: Did you also try with `checkbox.toggle()` instead of `checkbox.checked=false` ? ([docs](https://material.angular.io/components/checkbox/api#MatCheckbox))

Comment: @AndreiGătej Thanks but I cannot use toggle() as that will change some of them to true, when they should all be set to false. Besides that is not the issue - in the UI the checkboxes are correctly changing state. The problem is the test is not seeing that.

Comment: You could only toggle them if they are set to true: “checkbox.checked && checkbox.toggle()”

Comment: @AndreiGătej Thanks, I did try it just to see, and I get the same behaviour (works in the UI but not in the test). I believe it is some kind of timing issue with the test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is one of timing, so the test needs to `detectChanges` twice.

So this works:

```
  it('should uncheck all checkboxes when reset is called', () => {
    const checkboxInput = fixture.debugElement.query(
      By.css('.mat-checkbox-input')
    );
    const el = checkboxInput.nativeElement;
    el.click();
    fixture.detectChanges();
    component.reset();
    fixture.detectChanges();
    expect(el.checked).toBe(false);
  });
```

As does this:

```
  it('should uncheck all checkboxes when reset is called', async(() => {
    const checkboxInput = fixture.debugElement.query(
      By.css('.mat-checkbox-input')
    );
    const el = checkboxInput.nativeElement;
    el.click();
    fixture.detectChanges();
    component.reset();
    fixture.detectChanges();
    fixture.whenStable().then(() => {
      expect(el.checked).toBe(false);
    });
  }));
```